# Spectrum of a Frequency Modulated audio file(.mp3)

Tags: python

steps: get the audio file and convert it to an array using:

```
def Convert_Audio_to_Array(self, FILE_NAME, fs=44100):
    print("Converting Audio File to Numpy Array...")
    audio_file, sr = librosa.load(os.path.join(self.BASE_DIR, FILE_NAME), sr=fs) # convert t0 numpy array
    print(f"Conversion Successful with array/{audio_file.shape=}")
    return audio_file, sr
```

How do I plot its spectrum?

Comment: You probably need to do a Fourier transform on the array to return the frequencies.. https://librosa.org/doc/main/auto_examples/plot_display.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-display-py

Comment: Yes but before that i need to modulate the "audio_file" array which is where I am stuck. (I don't know how to perform FM modulation in python)

Comment: Why would you need to do FM? You did not mention this at all in your question

Comment: Sorry I totally missed it